# Peeking a UINavigationController makes content "jump"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

See https://gfycat.com/LightheartedUnimportantKingfisher or https://github.com/NathanJang/iOS-Preview-Demo/blob/master/Preview%20Demo/ViewController.swift for a simple demo.

I want to peek a view controller wrapped in a `UINavigationController` so that the user can see a title for the view controller being peeked. However, the content "jumps" when peeking, and changes position shortly after the view is peeked. How do I fix this?

I have created a ~15-line demo to show this effect in the links above. Here are my delegate methods for the lazy:

```
extension ViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let detailViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") else { return nil }
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailViewController)
        return navigationController
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        guard let detailViewController = (viewControllerToCommit as? UINavigationController)?.visibleViewController else { return }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

The only workaround I have found is to call `viewWillAppear` before returning the wrapper navigation controller being peeked, but obviously that is bad practice.